# Updating data adapter (for Autocompltxtv) from another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

My problem is that I can't update the data of my AcTview adapter, when I enter data from another of my fragment.

In `PageAdjuFragment` I have the ACTV `tv2` and his adapter `adapter2`.
The data of this adapter are created by `getListpart()` in `VenteFragment` (PageAdjuFragment extends VenteFragment).

I know that getListpart() and initpart() work cause when I relaunch my app, the new data appears in my actv.

I think that the problem is when I switching between my fragments, they are already launch so the data are initialized just one time at the start.

I navigate between fragment when i switch of page on my app. 3 fragments on 1 activity create with `MyPagerAdapter`

**here my code**

***The fragment***

```
public class PageAdjuFragment extends VenteFragment {
Context context = getActivity();

public PageAdjuFragment() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static PageAdjuFragment newInstance(String vente) {
    PageAdjuFragment myFragment = new PageAdjuFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("vente", vente);
    myFragment.setArguments(args);

    return myFragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_adju_layout, container, false);
    final Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btconfp);
    final RadioGroup radiopmt = (RadioGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.radiopmt);
    final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    final AutoCompleteTextView tv1 = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.actv1);
    final AutoCompleteTextView tv2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.actv2);
    final EditText tv3 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edt);

    // Recovery of the name of th folder/vente
    Bundle arg = getArguments();
    // final String vente = arg.getString("vente");
    VenteFragment.nomvente = arg.getString("vente");


    try {
        InitObjet();
        InitPart();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (String elem : getListpart()) {
        Log.v("part", elem);
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, this.getListobject());
    tv2.setAdapter(adapter2);





//some useless code ////////////////



 }
```

***The ActivityFragment***

```
public class VenteActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager2);
    creationPage();

}

public void creationPage() {
    // Creation of the list
    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

    // Recovery
    Intent sender = getIntent();
    String extraData = sender.getExtras().getString("vente");
    Log.v("Vente activity", extraData);
    // Add Fragments in a list
    Fragment frag1 = PageOffreFragment.newInstance(extraData); // frag1 //
                                                                // anymor
    fragments.add(frag1);

    Fragment frag2 = PageAdjuFragment.newInstance(extraData); // frag2 //
                                                                // anymor
    fragments.add(frag2);

    Fragment frag3 = PagePartFragment.newInstance(extraData); // frag3 //
                                                                // anymor
    fragments.add(frag3);

    // Creation of theadapter
    this.mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager2);

    // Affectation on the ViewPager
    //pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);


    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

        }
    });

}

// Overide for blocking the BACK Key of android device
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}


}
```

***The class for work on the fragment :***

```
public class VenteFragment extends Fragment {
protected static List<String> Listobject = null;
protected static List<String> Listpart = null;
protected static List<String> Listclient = null;
protected static String nomvente;

public List<String> getListobject() {
    return Listobject;
}

public void setListobject(List<String> listobject) {
    Listobject = listobject;
}

public List<String> getListpart() {
    return Listpart;
}

public void setListpart(List<String> listpart) {
    Listpart = listpart;
}

public List<String> getListclient() {
    return Listclient;
}

public void setListclient(List<String> listclient) {
    Listclient = listclient;
}


// Create the List of participant
public void InitClient() throws IOException {...}


// Create the List of participant
public void InitPart() throws IOException {
    Log.v("VFvente", this.nomvente);
    File DIR = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Vente Acta/ListeVente/" + this.nomvente);
    final String ADDRESS_FILE = DIR.toString() + "/" + "participant.csv"; // l'emplacement
                                                                            // de
                                                                            // achat.csv
    Log.v("VFchemin", ADDRESS_FILE);
    // if the file doesn't exit, create the file
    File f = new File(ADDRESS_FILE);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.createNewFile();
        Log.v("VFvente", "ici");
        return;
    }

    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>(); // liste contenant les
                                                    // element a adapter
                                                    // aux
                                                    // autotextview

    // on applique le reader sur le fichier
    CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(ADDRESS_FILE));
    List<String[]> liste = reader.readAll();
    int i = 0;
    for (String[] ligne : liste) {
        for (String col : ligne) {
            Log.v("ligne " + i, "col " + col);
        }
        i++;
    }
    for (String[] elem : liste) { // pour chaque ligne
        Log.v("VFdataelem0", elem[0]);
        Log.v("VFdataelem1", elem[1]);
        Log.v("VFdataelem2", elem[2]);
        data.add(elem[1] + " " + elem[2]); // le nom et prenom
        data.add(elem[0]); // le numero de participant pour la vente
    }

    reader.close();
    Log.v("VFvente", "fin");
    this.setListpart(data);
}

// Create the List of object
public void InitObjet() throws IOException {...}



}
```

***The Page Adapter***
    public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

```
List<Fragment> fragments;
FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

// On fournit à l'adapter la liste des fragments à afficher
public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    return this.fragments.get(pos);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
       return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

I have already try :

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
           return POSITION_NONE;
        }
```

or `adapter2.setNotifyOnChange(true);`
or `onResume`
**BUT** maybe at the wrong place

and

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            Log.d("onPageSelected: ", i + "");


            if(i == 0) {
                PageOffreFragment frg = (PageOffreFragment)mPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(pager, i);
                frg.onResume();
            } else if (i == 1){
                PageAdjuFragment frg = (PageAdjuFragment)mPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(pager, i);
                frg.onResume();

            }else if (i == 2) {
                PagePartFragment frg = (PagePartFragment)mPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(pager, i);
                frg.onResume();
            }

        }
```

in VenteActiivty

Nothing work :(

The creation is ok, the problem is the lifecycle of my fragment. (i think)
and where reload my fragment for update the list of data of my ACTV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I have found a solution: this is my new FragmentActivity:

```
 public class VenteActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager2);
    creationPage();

}

public void creationPage() {
    // Creation of the list
    final List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

    // Recovery
    Intent sender = getIntent();
    final String extraData = sender.getExtras().getString("vente");
    Log.v("Vente activity", extraData);

    // Add Fragments in a list
    final Fragment frag1 = PageOffreFragment.newInstance(extraData); // frag1
    fragments.add(frag1);
    final Fragment frag2 = PageAdjuFragment.newInstance(extraData); // frag2
    fragments.add(frag2);
    final Fragment frag3 = PagePartFragment.newInstance(extraData); // frag3
    fragments.add(frag3);

    // Creation of theadapter
    this.mPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager2);

    // Affectation on the ViewPager
    // pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            Log.d("onPageSelected: ", i + "");
            mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Before you call notifychange make sure you add the new data first to you arraylist then call notify change

Comment: `InitPart();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, this.getListpart());

adapter2.setNotifyOnChange(true);

tv2.setAdapter(adapter2);`

doesn't work